# getting data but unable to save it ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

This is my code for a service

```
function usersClicked() {
    var response;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'somedomain.com/get_users',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

In network tab, I am able to see the response but it is unable to alert data. No dialog is being shown. can anyone help me with this[image]

Response Header [image]

Comment: You have issue with server side code possibly. Open browser console and verify if you are getting data from http call

Comment: @binariedMe I'm able to get data, I checked in network tab

Comment: Can you confirm that the network tab shows an HTTP response code in the 200s?

Comment: or add error callback and check!

Comment: please paste a screen shot browser console

Comment: Can you paste the result you get by access the url you use in browser? Also indicate http status.

Comment: @binariedMe added screen shot

Comment: Just a wild guess of no alert allowed. Can you please instead use console.log(data);

Comment: @binariedMe not working even with console.log(data);

Comment: Ohkay. Now looking at the code I see that you probably didn't enable cross-domain request on server side. Can you please confirm?

Comment: You must be making request to a different domain that the one front end is.

Comment: Add all necessary information to the question. Which server are you targeting? Does it allow cors? Add an error handler to your ajax call, post the log. For debugging, never use alerts, but console.log

Comment: my backend is in local machine itself
I enabled cross-domain request on backend

Comment: Please show response header to confirm

Comment: @binariedMe added response headers image

Comment: Sorry bro. I am all out. Lets see if anyone else gets a clue.

Comment: You're using `jsonp`, which is "JSON with a callback" so it's likely not going to call your success function. You need to give it a callback function to call, if I'm not mistaken. See also [this comment on a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256983/jquery-ajax-call-for-cross-domain-with-jsonp-returns-status-200-but-error-fu?rq=1#comment42988959_27256983)